# Vue.js router doesn't see components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I've just initialized a Vue application and added some new routes. But they didn't work at all.

My router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import QuestionList from '@/components/pages/QuestionList'
import SessionList from '@/components/pages/SessionList'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/questions',
      name: 'QuestionList',
      component: QuestionList
    },
    {
      path: '/sessions',
      name: 'SessionList',
      component: SessionList
    },
  ]
})

export default router
```

My component:

```
<template>


<h1>test</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

When I go to localhost:8000/questions or localhost:8000/sessions nothing happens. + I don't see these components through Vue Dev Tools. What's wrong?

Comment: try `localhost:8000/#/sessions` with `#`

Comment: not enough info. try to set up demo online.

Comment: How do you use your router ? Is there `new Vue({  router });` in your code ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thank you, it works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in  [`official docs`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode) you should add hash like `localhost:8000/#/sessions`:

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.
>
> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload :

```
  const router = new VueRouter({
       mode: 'history',
        routes: [...]
  })
```

Comment: And don't forget to use `router-view` in html code :)